# how to send C2d messages from databricks ---> Azure IOT hub ---> iotDevice

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

my requirement is as below:

```
databricks ---> Azure IOT hub ---> Device1
```

I have some data processed and stored in dataframe with two columns `device_id and payload` in databricks. now I wanna send this payload to respective devices connected to my IOT hub using azure-iot-python-SDK

I am quite new to IOT as well as azure iot hub.. should i use `registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, data, properties=props)` in some loop to send the payload? is this right?

can someone please explain me what steps I should follow here.. and what considerations I am missing here

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. And you can try [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/main/azure-iot-hub/samples/iothub_registry_manager_c2d_sample.py) for example to test it on your Notebook.